# How do I use clojure.data.xml to lazily parse out records from an inputstream?

Tags: xml, clojure

Given the following xml, how can I lazily parse out contact records?
The goal is to get the xml structure of each contact element and pass it to a function that will handle importing that record into a database.

I'll be working with a very large file and would like to avoid loading the entire xml structure in memory.

I've done this before in java using Stax, but I'm trying to figure out how to do something similar in clojure.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<contact_list>
  <contact id="1">
    <first>Joe</first>
    <last>Smith</last>
    <email>joe@example.com</email>
  </contact>
  <contact id="2">
    <first>Jane</first>
    <last>Smith</last>
    <email>jane@example.com</email>
  </contact>
  <contact id="3">
    <first>John</first>
    <last>Smith</last>
    <email>John@example.com</email>
  </contact>
</contact_list>
```

Right now I've just got the code below that returns the entire structure.

```
(use '[clojure.data.xml :as xml])
(use '[clojure.java.io :as io])

(defn handle-contact 
  "Do something with a contact"
  [contact]
  (println contact)
)

(defn parse-contacts
  "Parse individual contact records"
  [x]
  (xml/parse (io/input-stream x)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the coolest features of Clojure - the result returned by `xml/parse` is a lazy data structure. It *looks* like it "returns the entire structure" but what it actually returns leverages Clojure's lazy sequences.

[Lazy sequences](http://clojure.org/sequences) are one of the language's core abstractions (and one of its primary strengths).

So there's no need for SAX or anything like that in Clojure - you get the ease of use of DOM-style access and the efficiency of SAX simultaneously.

In your case, given that your `<contact>` elements are all direct children of the root `<contact_list>` element, the following will give you a lazy sequence of contacts:

```
(:content (xml/parse (io/input-stream x)))
```